# Comparison of equal values in Quicksort

Tags: c++, algorithm, quicksort

I have an object that has three variables in it: a source vertex, a destination vertex, and a length. I have a Quicksort Algorithm that sorts an object by its length. However, I want it so that if I compare two objects and their lengths are equal, that my quicksort will sort the object with the smaller source vertex in front of the one with the larger source vertex. If those are also equal, I want to compare the destination vertexes. I want to sort the larger destination vertex in front of that with the smaller source vertex. This will all be done in an array. Below is my implementation of quicksort. Note that e[i] is my object which holds my vertexes and length.

```
void quickSort(edge *e, int left, int right)
{
  int i = left, j = right;
  int temp, temp1, temp2;
  while(i <= j)
  {
    while(e[i].getLength() < pivot)
      i++;
    while(e[j].getLength() > pivot)
      j--;
    if(i <= j)
    {
      temp = e[i].getLength();
      temp1 = e[i].getEdgeSrc();
      temp2 = e[i].getEdgeDes();
      e[i].setLength(e[j].getLength());
      e[i].setEdgeSrc(e[j].getEdgeSrc());
      e[i].setEdgeDes(e[j].getEdgeDes());
      e[j].setLength(temp);
      e[j].setEdgeSrc(temp1);
      e[j].setEdgeDes(temp2);
      i++;
      j--;
    } //if statement
  }///while loop
  if(left < j)
    quickSort(e, left, j);
  if(i < right)
    quickSort(e, i, right);
```

}

Might anyone know how / where to perform the sorting of the vertexes if the lengths are equal? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best define a comparison operator for the `edge` objects that does what you need it to do:

```
class edge
{
  /* ... */
public:

  bool operator<(const edge &other) const
  {
     /* Length is first criterion: */
     if (length < other.length)
        return true;
     /* Source vertex is second criterion: */
     else if ((length == other.length) && (src < other.src))
        return true;
     return false;
  }

  /* ... */
};
```

And then, inside your quick sort implementation, you use this operator to compare `edge` objects, rather than accessing `getLength()` etc. directly:

```
while(e[i].getLength() < pivot)
  i++;
```

becomes

```
while(e[i] < pivot)
  i++;
```

And

```
while(e[j].getLength() > pivot)
  j--;
```

becomes

```
while(pivot < e[j])
  j--;
```

Note that I've only defined `operator<`, not `operator>`, so I suggest using only that. Alternatively, you can define `operator>` as well.

Note that above I assume that `pivot` is a reference to the current pivot element. If it's actually an integer index to the current pivot, you'll need to replace it with `e[pivot]`.

---

Separate note: You might want to use `std::swap(e[i],e[j]);` instead of the long (and error-prone) sequence of get- and set-statements and the temporary variables.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a comparison function and call it rather than comparing the lengths. You don't define `pivot` anywhere in your code, but I assume it's the same type as is returned by `getLength()`. You will need to change `pivot` so that it's an index. Then, you write:

```
while (compareEdge(e[i], e[pivot]) < 0)
    i++;
while (compareEdge(e[j], e[pivot]) > 0)
    j--;
```

Your `compareEdge` function would compare the lengths. If those are equal then it compares the vertices as you described.